# SQL: how to average across groups, while taking a time constraint into account

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table named `orders` in a Postgres database that looks like this:

```
customer_id    order_id    order_date    price    product
1              2           2021-03-05    15       books
1              13          2022-03-07    3        music
1              14          2022-06-15    900      travel
1              11          2021-11-17    25       books
1              16          2022-08-03    32       books
2              4           2021-04-12    4        music
2              7           2021-06-29    9        music
2              20          2022-11-03    8        music
2              22          2022-11-07    575      travel
2              24          2022-11-20    95       food
3              3           2021-03-17    25       books
3              5           2021-06-01    650      travel
3              17          2022-08-17    1200     travel
3              19          2022-10-02    6        music
3              23          2022-11-08    70       food
4              9           2021-08-20    3200     travel
4              10          2021-10-29    2750     travel
4              15          2022-07-15    1820     travel
4              21          2022-11-05    8000     travel
4              25          2022-11-29    27       books
5              1           2021-01-04    3        music
5              6           2021-06-09    820      travel
5              8           2021-07-30    19       books
5              12          2021-12-10    22       music
5              18          2022-09-19    20       books
```

Here's a SQL Fiddle:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/262fc/1

I'd like to return the average money spent by customers *per product*, but **only consider orders within the first 12 months of a given customer's first purchase *within the given product group***.  (yes, this is challenging!)

For example, for customer 1, order ID 2 and order ID 11 would be factored into the average for `books`(because order ID 11 took place less than 12 months after customer 1's first order for `books`, which was order ID 2), but order ID 16 would **not** be factored into the average (because 8/3/22 is more than 12 months from customer 1's first purchase for `books`, which took place on 3/5/21).

Here is a matrix showing which orders would be included within a given product (denoted by "yes"):

[image]

The desired output would look as follows:

```
         average_spent
books    22.20
music    7.83
travel   1530.71 
food     82.50
```

How would I do this?

Thanks in advance for any assistance you can give!

Comment: Your specifications are not clear to me. Is the desired output just for `Customer 1`?

Comment: Do you want the desired output for the other customers too, in the same sql output?

Comment: @BenKoshy - no, the averages by product should take ALL customers into account (but only if a given order within a product category occurred less than 12 months after a given customer's first order in that product category).

Comment: The question is still not 100% clear for me. What would help me - and possibly others (including yourself) in solving these complex problems - is to break it down into a series of steps: 1. get customers first order by category, 2.....filter all customers based on the results of step 1 etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a subquery to check whether or not to include a product's price in the summation:

```
select o.product, sum(o.price)/count(*) val from orders o 
where o.order_date < (select min(o1.order_date) from orders o1 where 
      o1.product = o.product and o.user_id = o1.user_id) + interval '12 months' 
group by o.product
```

[See fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/6IzNoD0y)

Comment: How would I get the average number of orders?  (instead of average revenue)

Comment: Got it.  It should be:  `select o.product as product, sum(o.price)/count(*) as average_spend, count(o.order_id)::float / count(DISTINCT(o.user_id)) as average_orders from orders o`.